# R - Coerce list objects using percent (formattable)

Tags: r, formattable

I want to use `percent` from `formattable` package to coerce a dataset to percent form. The virgin dataset looks like below:

```
C1 C2  C3  C4
a  .01 .03 .3
b  .3  .5  .7
```

Expected result (ignoring decimals):

```
C1 C2  C3  C4
a  1%  3%  30%
b  30% 50% 70%
```

Now, I tried (number of columns might vary, but only C1 will have characters):

```
DF[, c(2:ncol(DF))] <- percent(DF[, c(2:ncol(DF))])
```

Showing error:

```
Error in as_numeric(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Now, When I tried it column wise, using a loop (`percent(DF[, i])`), it worked smoothly as expected. It seems that percent cannot coerce 2D data at once. However, **I want to know if there is a way to avoid the loop and come up with a beautiful solution.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) paste0(x *100, "%"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these kind of tasks I really like `dplyr::mutate_if`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(formattable)
DF %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, percent)
```

If not all of them should be transformed to % (because not a value between 0 and 1 for example), you could extend it to:

```
DF %>% mutate_if(function(x){all(between(x, 0, 1))}, percent)
```

Comment: WOW! `mutate_if` is awesome! Why did I not know this before!??!

Answer (score 1):

We need to loop through the columns

```
library(formattable)
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], percent)
```

---

This can be done with `base R`

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], function(x) paste0(x *100, "%"))
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer `sprintf`. `paste0` will certainly look uglier if there is truncation going on in the printing of `DF`

Comment: Thank you. However, I feel the `mutate_if` solution is better as it takes care of columns by specifying class, which, frankly was beyond my expectations. Your answer also worked well and taught me that I can exclude columns in the [] argument.

Comment: I prefer to use `percent` because it allows further numeric calculations. I used to use `paste0` before I came to know about that.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I don't understand what you mean by your comment. Can you please elaborate? I personally prefer `paste0` to `sprintf` because of easier syntax, but would like to know if that might cause some unexpected returns.